# Pulsar subscription backlog messages read without using consumer interface

Tags: apache-pulsar

What is the best way to read subscription backlog messages without using a Consumer Interface? We want to view/render subscription backlog messages payload and metadata. We looked through Pulsar admin and API docs but found nothing to get subscription backlog messages efficiently. We found a peek but it won't solve our use case. Basically,  are looking for some index-based reading from the pulsar subscription backlog specifically so that we don't need to pull everything at the same time and can control the number of messages pulled( paging). Has anyone built message management capability on top of Pulsar? Any help/pointers would be great

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Reader interface? It should allow you to read from a specific message ID or even read only specific messages.

Documentation: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/client-libraries-readers/